# Consulta SQL MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server

Verán, tengo la siguiente vista y estoy intentando que me muestre el valor máximo de cada cuota con una consulta. El problema es que me trae todos los valores de la cuota y yo solo necesito que se vea el máximo. 
Intenté con esta consulta:

```
SELECT nombre,domicilio, barrio, localidad, telefono,celular, descplanactual,
fechasorteo, planantes, valnom,monto,acidzona, cobrador, codigo, titulo, sorteo, cuota
FROM V_CuetaWeb
GROUP BY nombre,domicilio, barrio, localidad, telefono,celular, descplanactual,
fechasorteo, planantes, valnom,monto,acidzona, cobrador, codigo, titulo, sorteo, cuota
HAVING cuota = max(cuota)
```

También intenté con esta:

```
SELECT max(cuota) as cuota, nombre,domicilio, barrio, localidad, telefono,celular, descplanactual,
fechasorteo, planantes, valnom,monto,acidzona, cobrador, codigo, titulo, sorteo
FROM V_CuetaWeb
GROUP BY nombre,domicilio, barrio, localidad, telefono,celular, descplanactual,
fechasorteo, planantes, valnom,monto,acidzona, cobrador, codigo, titulo, sorteo
```

Adjunto la imagen con lo que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que muestre los datos del cliente y solo la cuota máxima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es una posibilidad, el ejercicio muestra los productos con la maxima cantidad de stock vendida en cualquier detalle.

Utilizo el ROW_Number() para enumerar por producto y que van a estar ordenado por cantidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego con una subconsulta y un where toma las filas que tienen la numeración 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
select ProductID,Quantity from
(select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by  productid  order by Quantity desc) as n, 
ProductID,Quantity from [Order Details]) as x
where x.n=1
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha servido de maravilla

Answer (score 3):

La primer consulta está mal puesto que estás incluyendo la cuota en el GROUP BY y así nunca se va a agregar.

La segunda parece correcta, pero es posible que haya columnas que necesites quitar para que permita que se agrupen las cuotas en una misma fila. Mi intuición dice que el monto va cambiando junto con la cuota y por ello no agrupa las filas de forma correcta. Tal vez si lo sumas podrías obtener un resultado más cercano o tal vez es otra columna la que tienes que revisar. En fin, revisa las filas que parezcan repetidas y encuentra cual es la columna con valores distintos para decidir si la incluyes en una función de agregado (`MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, `AVG`, etc) o si la eliminas de la consulta definitivamente.

Comment: Vale, gracias a ti me di cuenta que es por la fecha. Muchas gracias por la ayuda